# Drink made from fermented lemons?

Tags: fermentation, fruit

I had a neighbor who would bring out a large, 5-6 gallon? glass jar full of lemons(not sure what else was in there) outside for a little bit a few times a week. I know he was making some kind of fermented drink and that it took at least a hand full of months before it was ready. I want to try making some, but sadly I have moved away and I don't even know what it is called.

Anyone have any idea of what something like that would be called?

- <strike>I don't think it was lemoncello, it would be strange to make it with whole lemons.</strike>

Comment: Maybe he ran out of coriander and was making a wit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lemoncello is a possibility, but it is an infusion, not a fermentation of lemons.  Cover lemons with vokda and let sit for a few weeks, then remove lemons and sweeten to taste.  Works best with lemon zest, as whole lemons will have a lot of pith that will leave a bitter taste.

Comment: I've used this recipe several times with excellent results: http://www.italylogue.com/things-to-do/limoncello-recipe.html

Comment: I don't think it was lemoncello. But that does look good and I'll have to try making it.

Comment: I haven't seen anything else come close. Maybe it was made with whole lemons so it would be less work or something. Even though most recipes I found only had it take a week or two, I did find some recipes that took a few months. So unless someone else has any ideas, it must have been lemoncello.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Limoncello?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limoncello

Answer (score 1):

Might it have been [Skeeter Pee](http://www.skeeterpee.com/Skeeter_Pee/Recipe.html)?